# How Can I append JSON keys in While loop using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

> I have below sample code where I am trying to read from the json and
>   want to manipulate it in runtime.To achieve that I need the key value
>   pair in single record. Any Idea how can I append it to get below mentioned required
>   output?

**json file reading from :**

```
"sample_json": [
        {
        "Key1": "test"
        },
        {
        "key2": "dev"
        }
    ]
```

**Code:**

```
length = len(data['sample_json'])
count = 0
while count < length:
    dict_val = data['sample_json'][count]
    count +=1
    key, val = next(iter(dict_val.items()))
    env_values = {
        "name": str(key),
        "value": str(val)
    }
    print(env_values)
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'Key1', 'value': 'test'}
{'name': 'Key2', 'value': 'dev'}
```

**Required output**

```
{'name': 'Key1', 'value': 'test'},{'name': 'Key2', 'value': 'dev'}
```

Comment: Just so I'm understanding, you want duplicate keys? How do you expect to reference the one you want?

Comment: Oh! let me edit it. I need it in this manner - {'name': 'Key1', 'value': 'test'},{'name': 'Key2', 'value': 'dev'}

Comment: So something like this?  `env_values =  [{'name': k, 'value': v} for dicts in data['sample_json'] for k, v in dicts.items()]`